# Not able to see from where the branch was created from

Tags: bitbucket, git-branch

I am using bitbucket. I create a branch from another branch. But no where i can see this hierarchy as to from where this new branch was created from. Is there a way to make this hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
git merge-base master your-branch
```

to find the best common ancestor between two branches (usually the branching point).

otherwise you can use this command

> git reflog show --no-abbrev your-branch

It will output all changes made to the branch, including it's creation, for example (I created branch xxx from master branch):

Comment: How do i see this branch hierarchy in bitbucket ui?